# Specific C fifo implementation confusion

Tags: c, fifo

I need to use a FIFO for a project I'm working on. I found this implementation on the internet and I can't figure out what's going on in this function; I'm hoping someone can enlighten me.

```
/* Free an entire fifo */
void fifo_free(fifo_t *f, void (*freefn)(void *))
{
    fifonode_t *fn = f->f_head;
    fifonode_t *tmp;

    if (freefn == NULL)
        freefn = fifo_nullfree;

    while (fn) {
        (*freefn)(fn->fn_data);

        tmp = fn;
        fn = fn->fn_next;
        free(tmp);
    }

    free(f);
}

...

/*ARGSUSED*/
static void fifo_nullfree(void *arg)
{
    /* this function intentionally left blank */
}
```

1. See how it uses `void (*freefn)(void *)` as a parameter? Why? Why is that pointer passed into the function? What's the purpose of `(*freefn)(fn->fn_data)`
2. What's the point of these lines?

   ```
   if (freefn == NULL)
       freefn = fifo_nullfree;
   ```

   Wouldn't a comment in this situation be just as effective?

You can see a full copy of this implementation [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/dtrace/dtrace-78/tools/ctfconvert/fifo.c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The fifo_free function only knows how to free up memory used for `fifonode_t` items, it doesn't know what to do with the data (pointed to by fn_data) that is in those items. This is where `freefn` come in.

   The parameter `void (*freefn)(void *)` is a pointer to a function. The function takes a void pointer. This is used to free the data that is stored against each `fifonode_t` in your FIFO.
2. In some cases you might not need to do anything about freeing the extra data (say you were storing pointers to some other static data). In that case, you could pass NULL for `freefn` and the function will use `fifo_nullfree` as the function, which basically does nothing.

   Note: the `fifo_free` function could just as easily have done the if test inside the loop and only called the `freefn` function if it wasn't NULL. Possibly they have some reason not to.

Comment: What about '(*freefn)(fn->fn_data);' immediately after the while loop? Is this some sort of cast?

Comment: @JeffersonHudson, It means calling a function with the pointer to function. Since freefn is a pointer to a function, you can think (*freefn) as the function and (*freefn)(fn->fn_data), means you are calling the function along with the actual argument. Anyhow this line can also be written as freefn(fn->data). You may read a bit more here http://www.c-faq.com/ptrs/funccall.html

Comment: Am i correct in thinking the statement 'freefn = fifo_nullfree' makes the function pointer 'freen' point to the function fifo_nullfree()?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. (also, thanks @JonathanLeffler for the edit - looks much nicer).